# Using Realm with Swift on iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, realm

I have an app written in Swift that supports iOS 7.
I want to use Realm for my database, but according to their documentation the Swift library supports iOS 8 only.

I don't want to write Objective-C code in my app. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `RealmSwift` must be distributed as a dynamic framework, there's no real way to use it on iOS 7. Realm Objective-C should work just fine in Swift, albeit with a less 'native' feel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll go with Core Date unfortunately

Comment: @Ron.Kliffer To be clear, you don’t have to write Objective-C code to use Realm from Swift with iOS 7. You can use the “Realm Objective-C” library from Swift, writing only Swift language code. We are now encouraging people to build on “Realm Swift” instead, but you can still see what writing Swift code to use Realm Objective-C looks like in our [0.91.0 docs](http://realm.io/docs/objc/0.91.0/#models). I hope this helps.

Comment: @timanglade I know that. I just preferred using native Swift and not using bridging. I might wait until my app supports iOS 8 and up, should happen soon anyway